# In DataTemplate ,how to get the page's field by databinding?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

```
        <ListView
            x:Name="List"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind taglist}"
            SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                    <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="str"
                            Text="{x:Bind}" />
                        <ComboBox
                            ItemsSource="{binding source=combolist}"/>
                    </RelativePanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

combolist is a collection of string ,field of page insatnce.

the textblock control in datatemplate use a list as datasource,but the comboxes use another datasource (only datasource is same,but not mean same selection and control action).

i tried to use {binding} markupextension, but this kind of databinding cannot find the varity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `Page` a name:

```
<Page x:Name="thePage" ...
```

Bind to it using an `ElementName`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=combolist, ElementName=thePage}"/>
```

Finally, you need to turn `combolist` into a public *property*  as you cannot bind to fields:

```
public List<string> combolist { get; set; }
```

Comment: thank you sir,im really gratrful to you .It does work.